# How to parse this JSON to populate into APEX Collection and sort by date

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I've below `JSON` to parse using `APEX_JSON` in **Oracle 11gR2** database.
My requirement is to sort the date by `closed_at` and pick the latest close_reason. I'm thinking to populate `closed_at` and `close_reason` into APEX collection. Sort the date descending in apex_collections to pick the latest `close_reason`.

Can you please help with how to write `APEX_JSON.get_count` and `APEX_JSON.get_varchar2` to fetch `closed_at` and `close_reason`.

```
{"openings": [{
                "id": 5003,
                "opening_id": null,
                "status": "closed",
                "opened_at": "2020-11-30T20:09:56.487Z",
                "closed_at": "2020-12-02T22:43:45.736Z",
                "application_id": 76370003,
                "close_reason": null
            }, {
                "id": 8003,
                "opening_id": null,
                "status": "closed",
                "opened_at": "2020-11-30T20:59:02.267Z",
                "closed_at": "2020-12-04T11:07:26.087Z",
                "application_id": 45990003,
                "close_reason": {
                    "id": 7003,
                    "name": "Hire - New Headcount"
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

Thanks
Kishore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to use `APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2()`, need to parse `APEX_JSON.PARSE()` within a PL/SQL code. Rather than using PL/SQL, SQL might be used directly through use of `XMLTABLE` such as

```
WITH t1 AS
(
SELECT APEX_JSON.TO_XMLTYPE(jsdata) AS xml_data
  FROM t0 -- suppose your json data is inserted into jsdata column of this table
), t2 AS
(
  SELECT close_reason,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (ORDER BY TO_TIMESTAMP(closed_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff"Z"') DESC) AS rn
    FROM t1
   CROSS JOIN
         XMLTABLE('/json/openings/row'
                  PASSING xml_data
                  COLUMNS 
                    closed_at    VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'closed_at',
                    close_reason VARCHAR2(900) PATH 'close_reason/name'
                 ) 
)
SELECT close_reason 
  FROM t2
 WHERE rn = 1
```

in order to bring the latest close reason.

If you really need to use those functions given in the question, then use the following code block

```
DECLARE
   v_json VARCHAR2(32767); 
   v_ct   OWA.VC_ARR;
   v_cr   OWA.VC_ARR; 
   TYPE ts IS TABLE OF TIMESTAMP INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
   v_ts   ts;
   v_ts1  TIMESTAMP;
   idx    INT;
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     INTO v_json
     FROM t0;  -- there's no WHERE clause assuming only one row is to be inserted
   APEX_JSON.PARSE(v_json);

   FOR i IN 1..APEX_JSON.GET_COUNT('openings')
   LOOP
     v_ct(i) := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2('openings['||i||'].closed_at');
     v_ts(i) := TO_TIMESTAMP(v_ct(i), 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff"Z"');
     IF NVL(v_ts1, v_ts(i)) <= v_ts(i) THEN
       v_ts1 := v_ts(i);
       idx := i;
     END IF; 
     v_cr(i) := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2('openings['||i||'].close_reason.name');          
   END LOOP;    
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cr(idx));                     
END;
/
```